# React - Is there an clean way to update nested properties in a state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm struggling to update nested properties in a state, especially when arrays are involved.

I have data like this, adn trying to update the temperature when user touches the line:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "chicago",
        country: "us",
        data: [
            {
                temperature: 75,
                date: '2023-05-18'
            },
            {
                temperature: 60,
                date: '2023-05-20'
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

I managed to make it work but i feel like my code is a bit dirty, is there a better way to do this?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SectionList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () =>  {

 const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "chicago",
        country: "us",
        data: [
            {
                temperature: 75,
                date: '2023-05-18'
            },
            {
                temperature: 60,
                date: '2023-05-20'
            }
        ]
    }
])

 const addOneDegree = (item, index, section) => {
    let newItem = {...item}
    let newSection = {...section}
    let newData = [...data]
    newItem.temperature++
    newSection.data[index] = newItem
    newData[section.id] = newSection
    setData(newData)
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
            sections={data}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addOneDegree(item, index, section)}><Text>{item.temperature}°F - {item.date}</Text></TouchableOpacity>}
            renderSectionHeader={({section}) =>  <Text>{section.name} - {section.country}</Text>} 
        /> 
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: 60
  },
});
```

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer

Comment: "Clean" is subjective and your question is soliciting opinions which is considered off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Immer https://immerjs.github.io/immer/

Installation:

```js
npm install immer use-immer
```

Code:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SectionList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import { useImmer } from 'use-immer'; // new import

const App = () => {
  // change to "useImmer"
  const [data, setData] = useImmer([
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'chicago',
      country: 'us',
      data: [
        {
          temperature: 75,
          date: '2023-05-18',
        },
        {
          temperature: 60,
          date: '2023-05-20',
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  const addOneDegree = (item, index, section) => {
    // new setter
    setData((draft) => {
      draft[section.id].data[index].temperature++;
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SectionList
        sections={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        renderItem={({ item, index, section }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addOneDegree(item, index, section)}>
            <Text>
              {item.temperature}°F - {item.date}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
          <Text>
            {section.name} - {section.country}
          </Text>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: 60,
  },
});
```

Comment: That's really nice, I used useImmerReducer and got exactly what i wanted